# Proving that $m\leq 4$ when $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}=\sum_{i=1}^m \sqrt{d_i}$ with each $d_i/d_j$ non-square

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

The question has been [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3952063/prove-that-m-leq-4) on math.SE but had no response.

There are positive integers $a,b,c,d_i$, s.t. $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}=\sum_{i=1}^m \sqrt{d_i}$, and for any $i\ne j$, $\sqrt{d_i/d_j}$ is not a rational number. Prove that, $m\le 4$.

I tried some algebraic transformations, but they didn't work. Would it be related to [Galois Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory)?

Can anyone help?

Comment: (1) What is the motivation? (2) Why do you think this should hold?

Comment: (1)The motivation of producing this problem comes from an Euler project problem. It involves considering the radical splitting in this way.
(2)As we could use the arguments in abstract algebra about fields, The minimal polynomial of the left hand side has a degree less than or equal to eight, which indicates that $m$ is less than or equal to eight. However, as I tried many times, I think $m$ is smaller or equal to $4$ and all the $d_i$'s have the same pattern. I don't know exactly why this holds because I don't know the proof. If I know the proof, I may not ask this question XD.

Comment: the dimension of linear space spaned by $\{1,\sqrt{b},\sqrt{c},\sqrt{bc}\}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is no more than 4, so the dimension of linear space spaned by $(\sum_{i=1}^{m} \sqrt{d_{i}})^{2t}, t\in \mathbb{N}^*$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is no more than 4 then there is a contradiction if $m\geq 5$.

Comment: I can conclude this fact you listed up to the eighth to the last word, but could you elaborate more about where is the contradiction when $m$ is greater or equal to $5$? It seems that the fact of an even power does not indicate something to the odd power.

Comment: $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} \sqrt{d_i}\right)^{2 t}=\sum_{s \in\{0.1\}^{m}} \lambda_{2t, s} \prod_{i=1}^{m}\left(\sqrt{d_{i}}\right)^{s_{i}}$
, where $s=\left(s_{1}, \cdots, s_{m}\right) \in\{0,1\}^{m}$, 
$v_{t}$ is the vector composed of $\lambda_{2 t,s} \quad s \in\{0.1\}^{m}$. if we can prove 
$\operatorname{Rank}\left(v_{1}\left|v_{2}\right| \cdots\left|v_{n}\right| \cdots\right) \geqslant m>4$ then there is a contradition. For some special case the last rank inequality related to $\left(v_{1}\left|v_{2}\right| \cdots\left|v_{n}\right| \cdots\right)$ has some Vandermonde determinant structure

Comment: Can it hold for $m=4$? I do not think so.

Comment: by use the take trace method used by Fedor Petrov in the below answer, it seems we can prove $\operatorname{Rank}_{over \ \mathbb{Q}}\left(v_{1}\left|v_{2}\right| \cdots\left|v_{n}\right| \cdots\right)=2^m$ when $\prod_{i=1}^{m}\left(d_{i}\right)^{s_{i}}$ is not a square for all $s=\left(s_{1}, \cdots, s_{m}\right) \in\{0,1\}^{m}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I claim that $m\leqslant 2$. Taking the square we get $a+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}=(\sum d_i)+2\sum \sqrt{d_id_j}$.

By Besicovitch theorem, the square roots of positive integers do not admit a non-trivial linear dependence over $\mathbb{Q}$, that is, $\sum c_i\sqrt{n_i}\ne 0$ for non-zero rational coefficients $c_i$ and distinct squarefree positive integers $n_i$ (one-line proof: divide by $\sqrt{n_1}$ and take the trace).

Define a squarefree part $s(N)$ of a positive integer $N$ as the squarefree $t=s(N)$ such that $N=tr^2$ for an integer $r$.

If $m\geqslant 3$, then $d_1d_2$, $d_2d_3$, $d_1d_3$ have mutually distinct squarefree parts, also they are not equal to 1. Thus at least one of them is not equal neither to $s(b)$ nor $s(c)$. So this equality would contradict to Besicovitch theorem.

Comment: What is this "trace"?

Comment: Trace of an algebraic number $\alpha\in K$, where $K$ is a number field, is is the trace of the $\mathbb{Q}$-linear operator $x\to \alpha x$ in the space $K$ (regarded as a linear space over $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: I know. What I was trying to point out is that you use transitivity of the trace to see that it is zero in the big field generated by all the square roots.

Comment: @abx well, yes, I use this.

Comment: I can understand $\sum c_{i} \sqrt{n_{i}} \neq a$ for $a\neq 0$ because the trace of  $\sum c_{i} \sqrt{n_{i}}$ over the big field generated by all the square roots is 0 and the trace of $a\neq 0$ on it is not 0, but why we can prove $\sum c_{i} \sqrt{n_{i}} \neq 0$ by just look on the trace, it seems the trace of both side is 0, although I believe the result itself is true.

Comment: I see, when consider the trace of $\sum_{i\in I} c_{i} \frac{\sqrt{n_{i}}}{\sqrt{n_1}}$, the trace of it  over the big field generated by all the square roots is $[K: \mathbb{Q}]c_1\neq 0$, but the trace of 0 over the same field is 0.